# jQuery animate works different in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a script that displays fixed element on the bottom-right corner of the screen. This element must appear from bottom to top, as it does in Chrome and Firefox, but in IE it goes from top to bottom..

CSS:

```
.questionnaire {
  position: fixed;
  right: 25px;
  z-index: 150;
  display: none;
}
```

and JS:

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {

        var cookie = $.cookie('smth');
        resizeContent();
        if (cookie == 'que') {
            $('.questionnaire').css('display', 'block').animate({ top: collapsed }, 2000);
            $('.questionnaire span').addClass('collapsed');
        } else {
            $.cookie('smth', 'que', { path: '/', expires: 1000*60*20 });
            $('.questionnaire').css('display', 'block').animate({ top: expanded }, 2000);
            $('.questionnaire span').removeClass('collapsed');
        }   
    });
    function resizeContent() {
        windowHeight = window.innerHeight ? window.innerHeight : $(window).height();
        expanded = windowHeight - $('.questionnaire').height() + 'px';
        collapsed = windowHeight - $('.questionnaire').height() + 238 + 'px';
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: It'd be easier to help you if you could simplify the code above with just what's related to the animation.

Comment: @a.barbieri done

Comment: any errors in console??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you do not need to do your animation in jQuery. You can limit your code  to `add remove class`. CSS is more optimal way, no inline code and grater performance.

```js
$("#col").click(function() {
  $('.questionnaire').removeClass('expanded');
});
$("#ex").click(function() {
  $('.questionnaire').addClass('expanded');
});
```

```css
.questionnaire {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: red;
  right: 25px;
  bottom: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  z-index: -150; /* remove minus */
  display: block;
  width: 500px;
  transition: height 2s;
  -webkit-transition: height 2s;
}

.expanded {
  height: 230px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="col">Collapse</button>
<button type="button" id="ex">Expand</button>
<div class="questionnaire"></div>
```

Since this element is fixed there is no need to set it's display to none. This works the same on any browser that support `transition`.